# Combining selectors as variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

I'm thinking of what is the best way to combine selector, which i use as variables in my jQuery code. I want to use selectors as variable always, but the thing is that sometimes i want to use them in one statement, so i'm thinking what's the most elegant way to do it.

Should i use add ( (x+y).function... )? Or maybe add strings? Or maybe keep jQuery variables as only id with name so i can combine within single jQuery statement ($ that is)

```
x = $('#selectorOne');
y = $('#selectorTwo');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're declared as variables you can use `add()`:

```
x.add(y).something();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can store them in an array:

```
var selectors = [
    '#selector1',
    '#selector2',
    ....
];
```

and when you want to use them all together, do a comma separated `join()`

```
var alljoined = selectors.join(','); //join ALL selectors
$(alljoined).doSomethingToAll();     //and do something to all
```

you can also choose selectively:

```
var fewjoined = [                  //select a few selectors...
    selectors[1], 
    selectors[3],
    ...
].join(',');                       //..to join
$(fewjoined).doSomethingToAll();   //and do something
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is this the most elegant/effective way to solve this?

Comment: @Malyo there are a lot of ways to to it actually. This is what first came in mind when I read the post. Also, it calls all selectors once, rather than calling each individually and merge the results later.

Comment: Ok i'm gonna try it and keep the topic open for a while, maybe some interesting solutions will pop, thanks again

Comment: I've found that in this case using add() is much more efficient since i wanna minimize the code (especially the $ statement), altho using your method with add() could work as well, it's better when i have a really complex function to do. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

[Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)-You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in document order.

Example :

```
$("div,span,p.myClass").css("border","3px solid red");
```

or

[.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) - Add elements to the set of matched elements.

Example :

```
$("p").add("div").addClass("widget");
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer altho multiple selector is something i'm aware of, that's not the case in my problem, altho add method applies to my variable case.

Answer (score 0):

Since x and y are just arrays, one can use jQuery.merge to combine them. HTH

Comment: Well but i want to keep $ statement inside, so adding $ satement with $ statement doesn't seem like a good solution